# How to Select and Group By query which is already grouped with Over() ? - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle10g

I'm trying to refine following query:

```
    SELECT TID, INSERTDATE, TNAME, TSURNAME, TDATE1, TDATE2, TDATE3 FROM
    (SELECT T1.TID,T2.INSERTDATE, T1.TNAME, T1.TSURNAME,  T2.TDATE1, T2.TDATE2, T2.TDATE3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.TID ORDER BY T2.INSERTDATE DESC) AS RN
FROM MEMBER T1 INNER JOIN MEMBERPROMOTION T2 ON T1.TID=T2.TID WHERE SOME CLAUSES AND
(TDATE1 >= TO_TIMESTAMP('15/07/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TDATE1 <= TO_TIMESTAMP('14/08/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) OR 
(TDATE2 >= TO_TIMESTAMP('15/07/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TDATE2 <= TO_TIMESTAMP('14/08/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) OR
(TDATE3 >= TO_TIMESTAMP('15/07/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TDATE3 <= TO_TIMESTAMP('14/08/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))) 
 ORDERED WHERE RN = 1;
```

**MEMBER**

```
  TID  TNAME   TSURNAME
-------------------------------
   1    BLA   BLABLA    
   2    BL    BLBL
```

**MEMBERPROMOTIONS**

```
  MPID  TID  INSERTDATE     TDATE1       TDATE2       TDATE3
--------------------------------------------------------
   1     1   11/06/2012   19/07/2013    19/07/2013   19/07/2013
   2     1   05/08/2013   19/07/2014    19/07/2014   19/07/2014 
   3     2   05/08/2013   02/08/2014    21/07/2014   02/08/2014
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
  TID  INSERTDATE     TDATE1       TDATE2       TDATE3
--------------------------------------------------------
   1   05/08/2013   19/07/2014    19/07/2014   19/07/2014 
   2   05/08/2013   02/08/2014    21/07/2014   02/08/2014 
   2   05/08/2013   02/08/2014    21/07/2014   02/08/2014
```

MEMBER table has member information and it has relationship with MEMBERPROMOTIONS table on TID column.

As you see; I have date inputs and I'm selecting rows at least one of dates(date1,date2,date3) between input dates. I just want max(INSERTDATE) row so I used OVER().

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

If TDATE1, TDATE2 and TDATE3 is same I want single row return, otherwise I expect multiple rows. The point is I want to group by according to TDATE1, TDATE2 and TDATE3.

Comment: Not sure I'm following why you can't just apply an aggregate and a `group by` to the outer select. Can you add some sample data and show the expected results for that? (A cut-down but working query would also be helpful, as a self-contained example, rather than having `some jojns` etc.)

Comment: @AlexPoole I edited question with joins and sample data.

Comment: Sample and expected output would be useful too. At the moment that gets two rows, both with 05/08/2013, right? And you want to still get one row for TID 1, but three for TID 2 because the three dates are different? But all with the same INSERTDATE? Seems like you're trying to unpivot the three dates for comparison independently.

Comment: Expected result is added too. Yes, query orders INSERTDATE and get maximum INSERTDATE for each member. So query in question returns two rows with 05/08/2013 INSERTDATE. I just try to get two rows for TID=2 member also one row for TID=1 member because of TID 2 has different dates.

Comment: Main reason of why I'm doing this; I have members and they have 3 different promotion date for every year. And I have procedure gets two dates from operator and procedure gives promotion to members whom promotion date is between input dates. As you see in my query it gives one promotion if u have same dates also different dates. But customers want to give seperate promotions according to date1, date2 and date3 if they are not same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an unpivot to convert the three `TDATEx` columns into rows; then to compare each of those with your date range. You've tagged this as 10g so the 11g unpivot operator isn't available, so this needs to be done the old way:

```
SELECT MP.MPID, MP.TID, MP.INSERTDATE, T.RN AS TDATE_NUM,
  CASE T.RN
    WHEN 1 THEN MP.TDATE1
    WHEN 2 THEN MP.TDATE2
    WHEN 3 THEN MP.TDATE3
  END AS TDATE
FROM (SELECT LEVEL AS RN FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3) T
CROSS JOIN MEMBERPROMOTION MP
ORDER BY MP.MPID, RN;
```

Which gives you:

```
      MPID        TID INSERTDATE  TDATE_NUM TDATE    
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 11/06/2012          1 19/07/2013 
         1          1 11/06/2012          2 19/07/2013 
         1          1 11/06/2012          3 19/07/2013 
         2          1 05/08/2013          1 19/07/2014 
         2          1 05/08/2013          2 19/07/2014 
         2          1 05/08/2013          3 19/07/2014 
         3          2 05/08/2013          1 02/08/2014 
         3          2 05/08/2013          2 21/07/2014 
         3          2 05/08/2013          3 02/08/2014
```

Using that instead of your original table:

```
SELECT TID, MAX(INSERTDATE), TNAME, TSURNAME, TDATE
FROM (
  SELECT M.TID, MP.INSERTDATE, M.TNAME, M.TSURNAME, MP.TDATE_NUM, MP.TDATE
  FROM MEMBER M
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MP.MPID, MP.TID, MP.INSERTDATE, T.RN AS TDATE_NUM,
      CASE T.RN
        WHEN 1 THEN MP.TDATE1
        WHEN 2 THEN MP.TDATE2
        WHEN 3 THEN MP.TDATE3
      END AS TDATE
    FROM (SELECT LEVEL AS RN FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3) T
    CROSS JOIN MEMBERPROMOTION MP
  ) MP
  ON MP.TID=M.TID
  WHERE -- SOME CLAUSES AND
    MP.TDATE >= TO_TIMESTAMP('15/07/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  AND MP.TDATE <= TO_TIMESTAMP('14/08/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
)
GROUP BY TID, TNAME, TSURNAME, TDATE;
```

Gives:

```
       TID INSERTDATE TNAME      TSURNAME    TDATE_NUM TDATE    
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 05/08/2013 BLA        BLABLA              1 19/07/2014 
         1 05/08/2013 BLA        BLABLA              2 19/07/2014 
         1 05/08/2013 BLA        BLABLA              3 19/07/2014 
         2 05/08/2013 BL         BLBL                1 02/08/2014 
         2 05/08/2013 BL         BLBL                2 21/07/2014 
         2 05/08/2013 BL         BLBL                3 02/08/2014
```

And that can then be your inner query; and you can apply the group-by to that result set:

```
SELECT TID, MAX(INSERTDATE) AS INSERTDATE, TNAME, TSURNAME, TDATE
FROM (
  SELECT M.TID, MP.INSERTDATE, M.TNAME, M.TSURNAME, MP.TDATE_NUM, MP.TDATE
  FROM MEMBER M
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MP.MPID, MP.TID, MP.INSERTDATE, T.RN AS TDATE_NUM,
      CASE T.RN
        WHEN 1 THEN MP.TDATE1
        WHEN 2 THEN MP.TDATE2
        WHEN 3 THEN MP.TDATE3
      END AS TDATE
    FROM (SELECT LEVEL AS RN FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3) T
    CROSS JOIN MEMBERPROMOTION MP
  ) MP
  ON MP.TID=M.TID
  WHERE -- SOME CLAUSES AND
    MP.TDATE >= TO_TIMESTAMP('15/07/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  AND MP.TDATE <= TO_TIMESTAMP('14/08/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
)
GROUP BY TID, TNAME, TSURNAME, TDATE
ORDER BY TID, INSERTDATE, TDATE;
```

Giving:

```
       TID INSERTDATE TNAME      TSURNAME   TDATE    
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 05/08/2013 BLA        BLABLA     19/07/2014 
         2 05/08/2013 BL         BLBL       21/07/2014 
         2 05/08/2013 BL         BLBL       02/08/2014
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f25d8/1).